# At what dimensionality does knn (k-nearest neighbors) start to perform poorly?

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I know that a kNN search will perform more poorly as the dimensionality of the problem grows. I understand that 20 is considered quite high dimensionality for a kNN search. What I don't know is where it really starts to get bad between say 3 (I know kNN works pretty well), and 20 (I know kNN doesn't work too well).

Assuming a well balanced tree, does anyone know how average query speed relates to dimensionality between about 1 and 20 dimensions?

In so far as different kNN algorithms produce significantly different results I'm interested in that, but you can assume the Scikit Learn implementation as kNN as a baseline for the question.

Comment: Have you tried doing some measurements? Performance depends enormously on the type of data you use (and whatever index scicit uses). For a short example see [Fig.  32-35 here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf), for a strongly clustered dataset, KD-Trees perform 100 times worse than other indexes, in an evenly distributed dataset they are almost the same.

Comment: That reference is a perfect answer to the question. Thank you very much for that! @TilmannZ please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance depends enormously on the type of data you use (and whatever index scicit-learn uses). 
For a short example see [Fig. 32-35 here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf). In these examples, for a strongly clustered dataset (labelled CL-P), KD-Trees perform 100 times worse than some other indexes, for another, evenly distributed, dataset (CU-P) they are almost the same.